# What's the benefit of using 2 ground line (instead of 1) in a differential pair of SATA3 data cable?

Tags: differential

The following is a sata3 data cable picture taken from [wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/SATA3-TwinAxCable.jpg/410px-SATA3-TwinAxCable.jpg)

[image]

There are 4 wires for each differential pair, and I guess the two silver-colored cables are grounds, and the two bronze-colored cables are differential pairs.

My question is, what's the benefit of using two ground cables instead of one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture actually shows four ground wires (two on each side of each of the signal pairs). On the SATA connector, the middle two wires are connected to a single pin, so the connector has three ground pins.

The reason for these four wires is complex (mostly to do with crosstalk); it is well explained here: [Why do cables have multiple grounds?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180811/why-do-cables-have-multiple-grounds)

Comment: Thanks @Paul. It seems that two main purposes were mentioned in that thread, i.e., to alleviate both impedance mismatching (causing reflection) and magnetic field overlap (causing crosstalk).

Comment: You are right, although mismatching could also have been solved in other ways.